# Easier to Harvest Garden in Skyrim Hearthfire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

In Skyrim hearthfire, you can build homesteads. One feature of a homestead is the garden. In the garden, you can grow certain plants that can be harvested once every few days.

This is a very useful feature. However, it is relatively difficult to harvest the crops. Your cursor have to be pointed very accurately, and it is not quite clear where you have to point your cursor at. If you mispoint, you'll "activate the fertile soil" instead. This is especially true for something like the creep cluster.

Are there ways to make harvesting the plant easier? Are there suggestions on how to point the cursor to harvest the plants?

Answer (score 3):

You have to point your cursor directly over the surface of the object you are harvesting.

For example, if you are growing *Mora Tapinella*, then your cursor has to be directly over the mushroom itself in order to harvest it.  Anywhere else (dirt, air, stump) and you will activate the planter dialogue.

Whatever you grow will stack over time, so one strategy to avoid meticulous harvesting is to just harvest less often.  You will get just as many plants but it will be less of a headache.

Note: There is a bug with the creep cluster, where it is so low to the ground that it's practically impossible to harvest.

Comment: "practically impossible"?  Hardly.  I generally exercise my alchemy by making 15 potions of Creep Cluster, Mora Tapinella, and Scaly Pholiota every few days.  While I can't harvest them at a run, taking three seconds to aim my cursor is by no means the greatest inconvenience in my life.

Comment: Stacks overtime? What do you mean? I've always gotten exactly 3 Mora Tapinella, 5 creep clusters, and 5 scaly pholiota from one harvesting. Is this a feature only on the special edition?

Also, tjd, there is a bug with creep clusters, but only on the special edition.